# Least cost path with network extension

Tags: netlogo

I would like to draw the least-cost path between a polygon (composed of several patches) in which there is a wolf and all polygons situated in a radius of 6 around the wolf. Here is my code :

step 1 : I built a network as follows to use the network extension in Netlogo :

```
wolves-own [my-cost-of-path my-path] 
patches-own [polygon night-cost LCP-distance-between-polygons]
turtles-own [cost-of-turtle]
links-own [cost-of-link]

to create-network

ask patches [ 
if not any? turtles-here [ 
 sprout 1 [ 
  set shape "dot" 
  set color white
  set size 0.5 ] ] ] 

ask turtles [ 
 set cost-of-turtle [night-cost] of patch-here 
 create-links-with turtles-on neighbors ]  

ask links [ set cost-of-link sum [night-cost] of both-ends ]

end
```

Step 2: I defined the function "least-cost-path" as follows :

```
to-report least-cost-path [ID-polygon] 
let my-cost-of-path -1 

ask wolves [ 
foreach sort turtles-on patches with [plabel = ID-polygon] [  
  let turtle-on-polygon ? 
  nw:set-snapshot turtles links

 ask turtles-here [ let cost nw:weighted-distance-to turtle-on-polygon "cost-of-link"
    if my-cost-of-path = -1 or cost < my-cost-of-path [
      set my-cost-of-path cost
      set my-path nw:weighted-path-to turtle-on-polygon "cost-of-link" ] ] ]

foreach my-path [
  ask ? [ set color red
    set thickness 0.2 ] ] ]

report my-cost-of-path

end
```

Step 3 : I used the function "least-cost-path" to build the path between the wolf and all polygons situated in a radius of 6 around the wolf:

```
ask wolves [      
 ask patches in-radius 8 [ 
 let list-ID-polygon-in-buffer ( [plabel] of patches in-radius 8 ) 
 set list-ID-polygon-in-buffer remove-duplicates list-ID-polygon-in-buffer 
 set list-ID-polygon-in-buffer remove [plabel] of patch-here list-ID-polygon-in-buffer 
 set list-ID-polygon-in-buffer remove "" list-ID-polygon-in-buffer 

  foreach list-ID-polygon-in-buffer [ 
   let ID-polygon-in-buffer ? 
    ask patches with [plabel = ID-polygon-in-buffer] [ 
     set LCP-distance-between-polygons least-cost-path ID-polygon-in-buffer ] ] ] ]
```

With this code, I have two problems :

1) the variable "cost" in step 2 takes FALSE/TRUE. On the contrary, "cost" must be a number. Consequently, I have a error message : The < operator can be only used on two numbers.

2) In the step 2, the variables "my-cost-of-path" and "my-path" must be specific to wolves : wolves-own [ my-cost-of-path my-path]. I have a error message because in my code "my-cost-of-path" and "my-path" are not specific to turtles (these variables are situated in "ask turtles-here").

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 3):

#### Regarding 1):

`nw:weighted-distance-to` reports `false` if no path exists.

How can there be no path, since your network appears to be fully connected? Well, the problem is that you are not dealing only with the turtles in your network: you are asking a wolf to `ask turtles-here` to find some path. But *the wolf itself* is included in `turtles-here`, and the wolf is not connected to the network!

You could perhaps get away with `ask other turtles-here`, but you would have to be sure that there is no other wolf on the same patch.

The sanest thing to do is probably to create a separate breed for the nodes in your network. If you had a breed called `nodes`, you could say `ask nodes-here` and that would nicely solve your problem.

#### Regarding 2):

Your code as you posted it does not compile because you are trying to `let my-cost-of-path -1` at the top of your `least-cost-path` reporter, but `my-cost-of-path` is already a `wolf` variable. Your code is confusing to me, so I can't give you a complete solution.

Is your `least-cost-path` reporter supposed to operate on a local variable or on a wolf variable? If you need a local variable, it should have a different name. On the other hand, if you want to operate directly on your wolf variable, it probably doesn't make much sense for `least-cost-path` to be a reporter (and you certainly can't report `my-cost-of-path` at the end of it). You probably need to restructure things a bit...